# Problema ao fazer inputs aparecer e desaparecer com jquery

Tags: jquery, html5, bootstrap-4

Preciso fazer que alguns inputs no meu `form` da versão mobile fiquem ocultos e sejam exibidos ao clicar no botão chamado `Busca avançada` criei um código `jQuery` mais não está funcionando não sei o que estou fazendo de errado lembrando que estou usando `bootstrap 4` segue os meus códigos:

HTML:

Tipo
                            
                                Periodo de informação
                                2
                                3
                                4
                                5
                            
                        

                        
                            Número
                            
                        
                        
                            Ano
                            
                                Escolha um ano
                                2
                                3
                                4
                                5
                            
                        
                        
                            Busque por termo
                            
                        

                        
                             Buscar

```
            <button class="d-block d-sm-none advanced-btn" onclick="myFunction()">Busca avançada <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></button>
```

SCSS:

```
.advanced-btn{
    border: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    outline: none;
}
@media (max-width: $screen-xs-min) {
    .myDIV{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

JS:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("myDIV");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara se for só exibir o conteúdo da `div` pode fazer como no exemplo, mas, segue algumas considerações:

> - **1** - Se você deixar a classe `d-sm-none` no botão como está seu código, o botão vai ficar com display **none** e não vai ter como clicá-lo para aparecer a div que você quer.
> - **2** - Você disse que fez um código com **jQuery**, mas o seu exemplo está com **Javascript**.
> - **3** - Pq não deu certo, o **document.getElementByClassName()** por padrão retorna uma **NodeList**, ou seja, um array de elementos, que para poderem ser acessados é preciso indicar um índice como por exemplo **[0]**.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("myDIV");
x[0].style.display = "none";

function myFunction(){

    if(x[0].style.display == "none"){
      x[0].style.display = "block";
    }else{
      x[0].style.display = "none";
    }

    // x[0] pega a primeira div, se tivesse uma outra div com esta classe 
    // vc pegaria ela com x[1]
    
}
```

```css
#myDIV{
  margin: 10% 25%;
}
.advanced-btn{
    border: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    outline: none;
}
@media (max-width: $screen-xs-min) {
    .myDIV{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css">

<button class="btn d-block advanced-btn" onclick="myFunction();">Busca avançada <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></button>

<div class="myDIV" id="myDIV">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="texto qualquer">
  <br>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="texto qualquer">
</div>
```

Comment: ele não fecha de volta ? precisava que fecha-se tbm

Comment: Editei a resposta Kirito.

Comment: Se a resposta  lhe foi útil, considere aceitá-la para que a mesma possa ser fechada no site.